# (d.*) of GRASS GIS does not execute from standalone script

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script

I am in windows 10. All my module import works well and grass env for standalone script is fine. I tried to execute following commands from standalone script. Neither wx1 display gets executed nor it throws any error.

```
gscript.run_command('d.mon',start='wx1',resoultion='1')
gscript.run_command('d.rast',map='elevation')
```